# Ruby: how to set and freeze specific time for a testing purpose?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, functional-testing

I need to have specific current time in my test case to test some scenarios in application. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some gems do just that. I'd recommend you use [timecop](https://github.com/jtrupiano/timecop).

Other alternatives are listed on the ever reliable [ruby-toolbox](http://ruby-toolbox.com), in the ["time warp"](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/time_warping.html) category.

Comment: Ruby toolbox is a fantastic site.